# Remove line with specific word using tclsh

Tags: linux, tclsh

I have a paragraph like this:

```
"Nothing is worth more than the truth.
I like to say hello to him.
Give me peach or give me liberty.
Please say hello to strangers.
I'ts ok to say Hello to strangers."
```

I want to result:

```
"Nothing is worth more than the truth.
Give me peach or give me liberty."
```

if a line uses the word "hello" then remove that line and take only the line without that word.

I find some information in reference:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1ykB.png)

so I think ít as follow: regexp "^[^hello]" $line
but it doesn't work

Comment: tclsh, tcsh, tcl, or regular shell (/bin/sh)?

Comment: just tclsh for this

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your attempt of:

```
regexp "^[^hello]" $line
```

1. A good practice with Tcl regular expressions is to put your regex inside curly braces instead of double quotes.   Square brackets inside double quotes will be evaluated by Tcl as a command.
2. `^` means the beginning of the line in regular expression.
3. Characters inside square brackets in a regular expression are considered a "character-class".   `[^hello]` does not mean the opposite of matching "hello".   Instead, it matches a single character that is not `h`, `e`, `l`, or `o`.
4. Do you care about case?  If not, then add `-nocase`.

A Tcl expression, which you can use in an `if` statement to check that a line does not include "hello" (or "Hello") is simply this:

```
![regexp -nocase {hello} $line]
```